# Integrating Qt 4.7.2 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, qt, build, makefile

I am trying to add Qt 4.7.2 to my Visual Studio 2010. I downloaded the source code, changed the environment variables, ran a configure -no-webkit command (which ended successfully), and an nmake command (which also ended successfully). Afterwards, I installed the Qt Visual Studio Add-in 1.1.9. When in VS I go to Qt->Qt Options->Qt Versions and I add the current Qt Directory (4.7.2) it gives me this error:

> This Qt version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MSBUILD, supported MSVC.NET)

What should I do? Thank you!
Also, I am running on Windows 7 x64 if that is of any help.

Edit: The problem appears only with VS Add-In 1.1.9. To solve simply install the 1.1.8 version. I found it on a Russian website. Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up I was about to upgrade to 1.1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this yesterday, here's how:

- Open up the Visual Studio Command Prompt, navigate to your Qt folder
- execute "configure -platform win32-msvc2010 -debug-and-release -static -no-exceptions -no-accessibility -no-rtti -no-gif -no-libtiff -no-libjpeg -no-libmng -no-qt3support -no-openssl -no-dbus -no-phonon-backend -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-webkit"
- (those were my options, you can of course change them)
- execute nmake
- add an environment variable named QTDIR with your Qt folder as value (had to do that because the add-in failed to do so)
- now you can choose this folder to add a Qt version in the add-in

Comment: That wasn't the problem. There is a bug in version 1.1.9 of the Add-In which will be solved soon (hopefully). Thanks for the support, though! :)

Comment: forgot to mention - I'm using v1.1.8 :-)

Answer (score 1):

`configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2010`
will generate both a nmake makefile and a .sln file, build with either

you can also add

`-no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -fast`

Comment: so when I enter the nmake command i should write it as nmake -sln? I already added all those combinations and it didn't work. the problem, as you can read from my initial message, comes when I try to add Qt to Visual Studio.

Comment: Just run nmame (it also generates a makefile) or open the .sln and build as usual